# How do I add a constraint to check the first character of a value entered in a VARCHAR2 column in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I want to add a constraint that checks if the first value of a string (in this case Product_id) is a particular character. In this case I need the first character to be a 'P', while the rest can be any combination of numeric characters.

Thus far I have this when creating the table,

```
  CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
Product_id varchar2(6) CHECK (Product_id, SUBSTRING(1,1) = "P"); 
Description varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Qty_on_hand number(10) NOT NULL,
Reorder_level number(5),
Price_per_unit number(8,2)
);
```

It doesn't seem to work though. I'm sure it's a very simple syntax error but I can't spot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is syntax error

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
Product_id varchar2(6) CHECK ( SUBSTR(Product_id,1,1) = 'P'),
Description varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Qty_on_hand number(10) NOT NULL,
Reorder_level number(5),
Price_per_unit number(8,2)
);
```

Comment: Ugh, so obvious. Thank you @realspirituals!

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
Product_id varchar2(6) **CHECK (Product_id like 'P%')**; 
Description varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Qty_on_hand number(10) NOT NULL,
Reorder_level number(5),
Price_per_unit number(8,2)
);

Comment: Please also give some explanation regarding his question.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer